# При наведении на меню не сразу пропадает часть страницы, которое оно перекрывает

Tags: меню, hover

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link href="https://www.dortmax.ru/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style>.link_cust:hover .menu-top{border:1px solid black;}</style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="top_menu">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="menubg">
        <div class="menu">
          <ul id="nav">
            <li class="link_cust"><a rel="nofollow">Продукция </a>
              <ul>
                <li class="menu-top">
                  <div class="item-menu">
                    <div class="ssilka">Террасная доска</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="item-menu">
                    <div class="menuicon"></div>
                    <div class="ssilka">Регулируемые опоры</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="item-menu">
                    <div class="menuicon"></div>
                    <div class="ssilka">Перголы</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="item-menu">

                    <div class="menuicon"></div>
                    <div class="ssilka">Эксплуатируемая кровля</div>

                  </div>
                  <div class="item-menu">

                    <div class="menuicon"></div>
                    <div class="ssilka">Ступени из ДПК</div>

                  </div>
                  <div class="item-menu">

                    <div class="menuicon"></div>
                    <div class="ssilka">Тропическая древесина</div>

                  </div>
                  <div class="clear"></div>
                </li>
              </ul>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
          <div class="spec">
            <div class="zagl">
              <h1>Dortmax - производитель террасной доски</h1>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slidewrap" data-autorotate="1000">
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <ul class="slider" id="sliderName">
              <li class="slide">
                <div class="diagonal1">
                  <div class="diagtxt1">
                    <div class="zagld"><span>Atlas Concorde Cliff Beige</span></div>
                    <div class="txtd">
                      <span>Керамогранит для террас самонесущий. Матовая, чуть шероховатая структура поверхности обладает антискользящими свойствами и не впитывает грязь.</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
```

При наведении на меню не сразу пропадает часть страницы, которое оно перекрывает, подскажите, в какую сторону копать по данной проблеме.

Comment: Постарайтесь собрать минимальный пример для воспроизведения проблемы и добавить его прямо в вопрос. В текущем виде вы, во первых, заставляете участников ходить на какой-то левый сайт и ковырять там исходники в поисках проблемы. А во вторых - получив фикс, вы же сразу его примените, сделав вопрос полностью бесполезным для будущих посетителей.

Comment: исправил. правда код нормально работает только если скопировать в нотепад и запустить, а с сайта нет

Comment: CSS добавьте в пример - тогда все будет работать и тут

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У тебя на родительском теге `<ul>` весит `transition`, вот тебе и корень всех проблем. 
[image: transition]

Сделал небольшой фикс, прописал inline trnasition-duration `<ul style="transition-duration: 0s">`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link href="https://www.dortmax.ru/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style>.link_cust:hover .menu-top{border:1px solid black;}</style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="top_menu">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="menubg">
        <div class="menu">
          <ul id="nav">
            <li class="link_cust"><a rel="nofollow">Продукция </a>
              <ul style="transition-duration: 0s">
                <li class="menu-top">
                  <div class="item-menu">
                    <div class="ssilka">Террасная доска</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="item-menu">
                    <div class="menuicon"></div>
                    <div class="ssilka">Регулируемые опоры</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="item-menu">
                    <div class="menuicon"></div>
                    <div class="ssilka">Перголы</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="item-menu">

                    <div class="menuicon"></div>
                    <div class="ssilka">Эксплуатируемая кровля</div>

                  </div>
                  <div class="item-menu">

                    <div class="menuicon"></div>
                    <div class="ssilka">Ступени из ДПК</div>

                  </div>
                  <div class="item-menu">

                    <div class="menuicon"></div>
                    <div class="ssilka">Тропическая древесина</div>

                  </div>
                  <div class="clear"></div>
                </li>
              </ul>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
          <div class="spec">
            <div class="zagl">
              <h1>Dortmax - производитель террасной доски</h1>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slidewrap" data-autorotate="1000">
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <ul class="slider" id="sliderName">
              <li class="slide">
                <div class="diagonal1">
                  <div class="diagtxt1">
                    <div class="zagld"><span>Atlas Concorde Cliff Beige</span></div>
                    <div class="txtd">
                      <span>Керамогранит для террас самонесущий. Матовая, чуть шероховатая структура поверхности обладает антискользящими свойствами и не впитывает грязь.</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
```